# Import modules created locally

Tags: python, module

I am trying to learn how to import modules in python that are created locally. Below is a module that I created and saved in the python folder on my local disk.

[image]

When I try to call this module in another piece of code, I get an error-

[image]

I am using Jupyter notebook and both the module and code calling the module are in the same directory.

Can someone advise what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: jupyter notebook is not a python module. Python modules are made of python code. Jupyter notebooks are JSON.

Answer (score 3):

can you try this?

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:/Users/hchopra/Desktop/Python-Folder')
import myModule as m
m.fish()
```

Comment: Seems like teh syntax of the command is incorrect,  File "<ipython-input-1-b1569400ef42>", line 2
    sys.path.append('C:\Users\hchopra\Desktop\Python-Folder')
                   ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: @Himanshu can you try with regular slashes, instead of backslashes?

Comment: Also I have already added the path where the module is saved to the system path

Comment: backslash has a special meaning within strings. It is used in order to escape some commands. I edited my answer for your full path.

Comment: Thanks, I noticed I have put back slashes and changed them with regular slash, However, now I see another error-

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-6cbafbfca01b> in <module>()
      1 import sys
      2 sys.path.append ('C:/Users/hchopra/Desktop/Python-Folder')
----> 3 import myModule as m
      4 m.fish()

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'myModule'

Comment: are you sure you're appending sys.path before importing mymodule? is your module named "myModule.py"?

Comment: oh the problem is youre not importing a `python module`. its an ipython jupyter notebook file. (myModule.ipynb) check this out for the solution: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jupyter/notebook/blob/master/docs/source/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.ipynb

Comment: can you try deleting import statement and %run 'myModule.ipynb'?

Comment: you can either try the steps i provided in link above, or convert your myModule.ipynb file into a python module (myModule.py) and import it as I stated

Comment: Yilmaz- Can you please elaborate a it more on how to convert ipynb file to a python module?

Comment: @Himanshu just copy the code into a .py file? I cant help any further since I dont use jupyter myself:p